# How can I get the review count on review's list.phtml in Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.8, review

How can I get the review count on review's list.phtml?

```
frontend\base\default\template\review/product/view/list.phtml
```

I get an error when I use this code in this page,

```
<?php
// Get the number of reviews of the product on the product page.
$storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->load($_product->getId());

/* @var $summaryData Mage_Review_Model_Review_Summary */

/*

array(
['primary_id'] => 147
['entity_pk_value'] => 166
['entity_type'] => 1
['reviews_count'] => 1
['rating_summary'] => 80
['store_id'] => 1
)
*/
//var_dump($summaryData['reviews_count']);
?>
```

error,

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
```

While the count on `frontend\base\default\template\review/product/view/count.phtml` will always return  **empty**

```
<?php if (!empty($count)):?>
    <a href="#customer-reviews" class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('%s Review(s)', $count) ?></a>
<?php endif;?>
```

Any idea why?

I have code in my catalog.xml's `<catalog_product_view translate="label">`,

```
           <!-- adding review to the product page -->
            <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_review_list.toolbar">
                <action method="setLimit"><limit>2</limit></action>
            </block>
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
                <block type="core/template" name="product_review_list.count" template="review/product/view/count.phtml" />
                <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form"/>
            </block>
            <!-- adding review to the product page -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error that you are seeing about `getId` is because there is no object for `$_product`, the block `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List` has a function `getProductId` so you should be able to update your code as follows.

```
$summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->load($this->getProductId());
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try very simple code It's work for me.

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short')?>
```

It's look like attached screenshot.[image]